# User Input from textbox1 > store in a list > output in textbox2

Tags: c#

I just have a question regarding C# list. I am a totally noob when it comes to programming and I'm really sorry for being a bird brainer. I am doing some practice coding and I am creating a simple program that will allow users to input names through textbox1 and then once they press the button1, the names will be stored in a List and will be output on textbox2.

I am having hard time storing the data from textbox1. Checked it online but I haven't found the right article for my concern so I'm trying my luck here.

Sorry guys, I forgot to mention I am using Winforms.

Thank you so much for the fast replies.

Comment: Post your code so we can see where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: You say C#, but are you using winforms, web-pages, mvc, or other?

Answer (score 2):

assuming winforms...

- Drag and drop 2 lists and a button onto your designer.
- drag a button onto your designer
- double-click your button to automatically create an event
- make a list structure somewhere inside your form to store the list
- instantiate your list in the form constructor
- in the `button1_Click` event add the text of `textbox1` to the list
- generate the text of 1textbox2`

here is an example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            list = new List<string>();
        }

        List<string> list;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            list.Add(textBox1.Text);


            string txt = "";
            foreach(string s in list)
            {
                txt += s + " ";
            }
            textBox2.Text = txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will study how the code works once I come back home. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sir, I tried you're code and it did work. Awesome! I just have a question, why did you declare the list under the Form and you created another instance above the private void buttom1_Click?

Comment: @user2117433 I don't know, I just kinda slapped it in there So long as it's inside the class but not inside any methods it'll compile.  It can be at the bottom, top, or between methods.  Order doesn't matter, except for code readability.

Comment: If you had that `list = new List<string>();` declared inside the button every time you click the button it would create a new list.  Rather then iterate through the list to add it to the textbox.

Comment: Oh, that's why. I used to put my array and list inside my button_click method. That's why whenever I tried displaying the total number of value inside my array, it displays the default value for index 0. That's food for my mind. Thanks Greg.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```
string name = Textbox1.Text;
ListBox1.Add(name);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. I got this code before I post. It actually worked then I decided to add a little spice on the program by displaying all of the data which are stored in the list. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If your utilizing a traditional Windows Form Application; I'm not sure you meant to store the data in another Text Box.  But a List Box may be more along your goal.

1. Drag the following: Textbox, Second Textbox, Listbox, and Button from the toolbox to your Form.
2. Adjust them however you would like, treat them like a canvas for a painting.
3. Once it appears to be configured how you would like double click the Button.

At this point Visual Studio will leave Designer View and go into Code View.  So you'll be able to see the code.  It will automatically place you in the Button code block.

These blocks are quite important, as you progress you'll notice how C# is structured.

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Logic to add will go in here.
}
```

What does this mean?

- Private : Is the modifier, it means it is restricted to this class.
- Void: Means it isn't asking for a return type.
- button1_click: That is the name of the button, you can change that within it's Properties.  It's good practice to name the component infront so you know what your working with.

What that entire block is, is an Event.  So when it is clicked it will perform an action.  That is what it means; so this is where your goal is implemented:

```
private void btnAddToList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // Test to ensure it isn't null.
       if(txtAddText.Text != String.EmptyOrNull)
       {
            // Declare a variable with the initial textbox value.
            string txtVar = txtAddText.Text;

            // Has the second textbox inherit value from other Textbox.
            txtNewText = txtVar

           // Now Add it to a Listbox.
           lstContainer.Items.Add(txtAddText.Text + DateTime.Now());
       }

       else 
       {
            // Null or Empty Character, Error Message.
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry, please enter a valid entry");
       }
}
```

That will provide the fundamental knowledge, but as you can see from your other examples they do it differently.  You'll notice that bugs can exist in such logic if you aren't careful.  Which you'll learn to identify based on the structure you configure.

Hopefully this is helpful, and it looks like a lot of others did some terrific post for you as well.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a Guru. Thanks for explaining those words to me. Now it become clearer.

Comment: I'm happy to help, a book I'd highly recommend is C# 5.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference, it will explain a lot of core concepts in great detail.  Also if you don't understand you can Google that topic and find books or lessons specific to that item.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Will look for that book.

Answer (score 0):

Within the button1 click listener (if you don't have this hook go into the GUI builder view and double click on the button, it will automatically create and register the listener for you), add the following code;

```
  textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text; // set tb2 = tb1
  textbox1.Text = System.String.Empty; // clear tb1
```

Now, in your post you say store the data in a list, but you don't specify how the user is to input that data so it's hard to give you a specific answer. If the names are say separated by commas to get an array with all the names you could simply do;

```
  string[] names = textbox1.Text.Split(',');
```

However, from your post it doesn't seem you want to store the data in a list at all. If you just want the input in `textbox1` to be displayed in `textbox2` upon clicking the input button then use use the first code snippet. If you go the second route, you'll have to convert the array back into a single string. This can be done easily with a for loop.

```
 string result = System.String.Empty;
 for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
      result = result + names[i] + " ";
```

To make `textbox2` display what's in `textbox1` and display the number of names;

```
  textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text; // set tb2 = tb1
  string[] names = textbox1.Text.Split(','); // i use a comma but use whatever
  // separates the names might just want ' ' for whitespace
  textbox1.Text = System.String.Empty; // clear tb1
  MessageBox.Show("You entered " + names.Count.ToString() + " names."); // show the names count
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try to study this code later. Thanks for explaining as well line per line, this is a great help.

Comment: BTW sorry forgot to mention, I am trying to input a value such as name from textbox1 and then once I click the button, it will display the current data added on textbox2 and display a messagebox saying the total number stored in list ( names.Count ).

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

```
    List<string> mylist=new List<string>();
    mylist.Add(textbox1.Text);
    textbox2.Text=mylist[mylist.Count - 1]
```

First you create a list of string objects.
Then add the text from textbox1 to the end of the list.
Then get the last element you added from the list by getting the length of the list and subtracting 1 since in C# collections are 0 based and the first element is [0] and not [1].

Comment: Thanks for this. I will study how the code works once I come back home. BTW, if the user entered a value from textbox1, will that value be stored somewhere/virtual memory? So we can pull it out anytime and display in textbox2?

Comment: @user2117433 All of the data submitted from textbox1 will be stored in the mylist collection. You can at any time reference any of the values stored in the list by doing mylist[indexOfItem]. This means that mylist[0] will return the first element you entered in the list and you can increment it as needed to retrieve each element in the list. If I didn't answer your question please let me know so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something simple as this:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string[] names = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine, "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     //you can add more parameters for splitting the string
     textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", names);
     //you can replace the comma with something more suitable for you
}
```

The first line splits the string that you entered in the textBox1 (hence names separated by newlines, blank characters or commas) into array of string (instead of list that you requested) and the second line joins the strings into one big string of names separated by commas and puts it into the textBox2

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I will study the code and try to apply it in the program once I come back home.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShowAllSaveNameAndCountApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<string> ourList=new List<string>();


        string txt =" ";
        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ourList.Add(textBoxEntryName.Text);



            foreach (string s in ourList)
            {
                txt+= s+ "\n ";


            }
            textBoxEntryName.Clear();

           ourList.Clear();


        }



        private void buttonShowAllName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxShowName.Text = txt;
        }
    }
}
```